# DDD: Where to place domain event handlers?

Tags: domain-driven-design, event

Could you tell me your opinion that which layer is the right one to place domain event handlers in DDD? For example, I have application service to add a new contract and I'd like to send an email notification to the contact person, when the contract has added, so is that email sender (which handle ContractAdded event) application service or domain service or something else?

Answer (score 27):

I place domain event handlers in application layer.

Domain event is a way to tell the outside layers (or outside world) that something happened in the domain layer. What to do with the event depends on the application. Application may notify user about changes or may call another domain to do something. Application is responsible for orchestrating domain operations  in reaction on user actions, web requests or domain events.

Comment: +1 for the application layer. In a pub-sub design, the domain event may activate generic logic in different places/systems/microsservices. If one of the subscribers is an application modeled using DDD, the event is triggering some processing in that application/BC. This processing may require transaction demarcation, access control, coordination that is typically performed at the application layer.

Answer (score 9):

I place Domain Event Handlers in Domain layer as a domain interface `IDomainEventHandler`.

An example of a Domain Event Handler is a policy that subscribes to certain domain event in order to initialize a new transaction (e.g: in order to trigger a new domain command), therefore it makes sense to have it in Domain layer since it's related to business logic.

We could think of an example where an order is confirmed and therefore an invoice request should be created.
We have an event `OrderConfirmedEvent` that has happened. A policy in our domain would be in charge of subscribing to this event and creating a domain command `RequestInvoice` that will be handled by the command handler and dealt by it accordingly.

If we had this event handler in application layer it would mean that the application layer, in addition to orchestrating user's actions, would execute some business logic, which seems incorrect.

However we have

Comment: I agree with this answer, you put domain event handlers inside of the domain, you can listen inside the domain and create VO's or Entities.

Comment: Although microsoft docs says this 
Handling the domain events is an application concern. The domain model layer should only focus on the domain logic—things that a domain expert would understand, not application infrastructure like handlers and side-effect persistence actions using repositories. Therefore, the application layer level is where you should have domain event handlers triggering actions when a domain event is raised.

Comment: I believe it can be both. You can very well have events and handlers in both the application and the domain layers. You probably don't want to listen from one layer to the other, if you can avoid it (if you can't, you might have modeled your application slightly wrong, I think).

Answer (score 7):

The original DDD book (Evans 2004) explains the application layer as a thin layer which exercises domain objects in response to the user's action. Typical event handlers for domain events therefore don't belong in the application layer.

It may make sense to place some of them in the domain layer, as long as you don't break the layering by creating an upwards dependency.

If you have a infrastructure layer that is below the domain layer, the event handler can't be there since it would break the layering.

If you have an adapters layer that is above the domain layer, you can create an event handler there. Check out [Hexagonal architecture](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture).