DDD -Can an aggregate consumes its own events?
I'm facing to an issue with my design in DDD with "Always valid Domain Model" principale and eventual consistency.
I have an aggregate with several public methods to mutate its state.
class Aggregate {

  public methodA() {
     // mutates aggregate's state
  }

  public methodB() {
     // mutates aggregate's state
  }

}


However, I have a requirement to refresh the value of a status after each mutation.

A naïve approch would be to call a private refreshStatus() method at the end of each method.
Described as below:
class Aggregate {

  private String status;

  public methodA() {
     // mutates aggregate's state
     this.refreshStatus();
  }

  public methodB() {
     // mutates aggregate's state
     this.refreshStatus();
  }

  private refreshStatus() {
     // Apply logic to refresh the value of the status, depending aggregate state
  }

}

This approach is a little bit headache, because developers should be aware to call this refreshStatus() method for all new methods implemented. Depending business needs, another private methods can be also called after a state change. It becomes cumbersome
A work around to solve this issue is to let mutation methods registers a new event to notify that "something happened" in the aggregate.
Then, we can react to that event to trigger the refreshStatus() method implicitly, at a centralized place.
class Aggregate {

  private String status;

  public methodA() {
     // mutates aggregate's state
     this.registerEvent(AggregateUpdated()); // register new event
  }

  public methodB() {
     // mutates aggregate's state
     this.registerEvent(AggregateUpdated()); // register new event
  }

  public refreshStatus() { // expoose publiclty the refresh method
     // Apply logic
  }

}

class AppService {

  @OnEvent(AggregateUpdated.class)
  public refreshAggregateStatus(AggregateUpdatedEvent event) {
    aggregate.refreshStatus() // react to events to refresh the aggregate's status
  }

}

But, with this approach, we have an aggregate that react to its owns events. Is a bad practice to do that ? It's OK to have an eventual consistency instead of an atomic consistency on the same aggregate ?
An another approch would be to have a listener of event directly in the aggregate, but I'm not sure this solution is a good one.

class Aggregate {

  @OnEvent(AggregateUpdated.class)
  public refreshStatus(AggregateUpdatedEvent event) {
    this.status = // logic to compute new status value
  }

}


You do answer your own question, in my opinion.  If you are fine with eventual consistency, there is no problem in having an aggregate raise events for which it is the target of, conceptually.  I would not have a listener on the aggregate, though, and would defer for a proper event listener as a standalone handler, because that aggregate would need to be retrieved from your persistence layer to have the change applied to it.  Your handler would retrieve it from the repository, apply the change, and then persist it back.

Thanks @JosephFerris for your reply, I will follow this way :)

I'm agree with you that isn't a good idea to put listner in aggregate. But can I deport this logic in a Domain service or Application service is prefered ?

I prefer keeping events limited to the domain, but that is because I tend to lean into CQRS approaches more, and fully isolate the domain from the application.  Ultimately, this comes down to personal preference, largely, and you can see valid arguments for each, here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/325996/ddd-where-to-place-domain-event-handlers

In using that kind of approach, that means that my domain event handlers would then create a command, which is handled by a command handler, which in turn will execute a domain service which makes those changes against the repository.

DDD is a balancing excercise, and there are so many approaches to take.  Ultimately, you have to decide what level of complexity you want, and deal with the trade-offs of simpler approaches potentially diverging from "pure" DDD tenets.  You likely will end up creating some sort of framework based on what you decide, which means that it is a high cost of entry, in terms of effort.  But, once you establish those patterns, it becomes easier to extend your domain over time.

I’m curious about this status. Why is every method mutating it? Is it a business concept used for decision making or validation, or something technical?

Thanks @JosephFerris for your inputs, it's clearer to me now :)

@RikD, Not technical purpose. The status is calculated depending the state of the object  about business concept. For example, 'SCHEDULED' status corresponding to an object where all fields are provided.

The issue here is rather simple... status isn't a property. It's a method. Have you considered public getStatus? Or if your language allows get status?

Yes, I already thought about that. But I have to mark the entity with a status property to retrieve them from persistence. A property computed dynamically would be more tricky to handle this.

Trickier than some sort of magic event listening system? I obviously don't know the details of your persistence code, but I can't imagine including the result of getStatus in your data would be that difficult or tricky. A computed property isn't exactly ground-breaking.

Question improvement: This approach is a little bit headache, because developers should be aware → [...] need to be aware

A practical perspective: you just replaced calls to refreshStatus with registerEvent. I don't see any any gain in this. But I see much more complex logic. This is harder to understand, maintain, debug. I wouldn't go for that.
